# Link agent app with enrolled device MDM iOS

Tags: ios, mdm

When enrolling device to a MDM server, device will send device UDID to server for identifying. In that device, I also instal an agent app, it needs to get the device UDID and use that as a key to communicate with server, thus server can know that which enrolled device is sending the message. However, the problem is Apple has limited the right to get device UDID from coding. I have no way to link the app and the device by an unique key.

I found some solutions for linking by using Managed Apps Configuration and storing an identifierForVendor key instead of UDID inside Keychain.

For the Managed Apps Configuration solution, it's only push data to managed app, so cannot apply for unmanaged app in my case.

For storing identifierForVendor key inside Keychain, my idea is the app will get that key and send to server, meanwhile, server will also query device to get that value (include device UDID). Then it'll compare retried key with the key sent from agent app and match them. But the problem is I cannot find out any MDM command to query the device keychain to get that value.

So my questions are:

1. How can I query the device keychain to get my key by using MDM service?
2. Is there any solution else for how to link the agent app with enrolled device?

---

**EDIT**
I have found a solution that could work.
After install the *.mobileconfig profile, device will send it's UDID value to server. Then from Web Server, it will open the app on device by URL-Scheme and attach the UDID to there. From within the app, it can handle to get this value in the method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

But the problem is how can Web Server know on which device the app will be opened to attach the correct UDID? Let say I have two devices, device1 and device2. When I open the app on device1, how can I know that the target device is device1 and attach UDID of device1 to the command but not value of device2?

Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: Can you use enterprise distribution rather than app store distribution to install your agent?  Then you could use private APIs to read UDID

Comment: I'm looking into private APIs to get UDID but haven't found one, could you recommend any of it?

Comment: hmm.  I just assumed that you could, but it seems that even with private APIs you can't access the UDID anymore.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Do you know about can server open the app by URL-scheme which contents UDID, then app can get that value? I'm not clear about this one.

Comment: I think that could work.  I am not familiar with how the MDM profile registration works, but presumably your web server can send a URI to the device - If you already had your app installed with a registered URL-scheme your could redirect to your app and include the UDID in the URI.  I know I had to install the MobileIron app before I registered my device, so I presume that is how they do it

Comment: Great, thanks for pointing me out. I'll try with this solution to see can it work or not.